# Why am I getting the following error - non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting the following error, I don't know why! Please be descriptive.

> non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String Hello() {
        String name = DemoController.getName();
        return "Hello";
    }
}

package com.example.demo;

public class DemoController {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Both the classes are in same package.

Comment: If you call it like `DemoController.getName();`, then it would be expected for this method to be static. You don't call this method on an object but on a class. In other case, if you want to call this method from an existing object, you should pass it to the calling function - in this example, `Hello(DemoController myController)`.

Answer (score 2):

- Either you could *modify* the method getName as *static* or access it using an instance of DemoController.
- Since getName is non static, its an instance method and exists only for an instance.